# UITextView Paging Enabled Text cut off

Tags: iphone, pagination

I am using a UITextView and enabling paging (in both IB and programatically toggling it on and off). There's a lot of text and when scrolling with paging enabled sometimes the first and/or last line of the currently viewable text ends up halfway in view and half out of view at the bottom or top of the frame so you can only see the top or bottom half of that line of text.   (I hope I'm explaining that correctly)

Does anyone know a way to insure that it pages correctly so it there's no lines of text half cut off??

A few notes
1. The font size is adjustable by the user.
2. I've tried setContentOffset,setContentInset,setContentSize and it's not helping (unless I'm using them wrong)
3. I am using a txt file to populate the UITextView

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: UPDATE:  I've been doing a ton a research and I think it can possibly be done with the NSString (UIKit Additions) but still can't figure it out.  Can anyone help??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. As such I do not believe `UITextView` actually supports paging as this is a feature of `UIScrollView`. Can you please take a step back and explain the end goal, as it sounds like rendering an `NSString` in to a `UIScrollView` might be actually what you want, instead of a `UITextView`.