# Detect when a UITextView has finished scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitextview

Is there a way to detect when a UITextView has finished scrolling?  As a note, I allow the user to enable or disable paging.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, which has a [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) class for controlling behaviour related to scrolling. One of its methods is [`scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:). You can make your view controller implement this protocol, set your `UITextView`'s `delegate` property to the view controller, and then implement the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` method. When the method is called, the `UITextView` will have finished scrolling. e.g.:

in .h:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

in .m:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"Finished scrolling");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think I got most of that except for setting the UITextView's delegate property to the view controller.  Can you clarify on that?  (I'm a newbie)

Comment: Sure. Once you have a delegate (in your case, your view controller), you need to tell the UITextView who the delegate is. You can do this visually in Interface Builder (click on the UITextView, bring up the Connections Inspector, drag from the `delegate` property to File's Owner), or inside code, inside your view controller's viewDidLoad method, with something like "myTextView.delegate = self;"

Comment: Thanks! That worked!  One thing:  When I did it via the code(myTextView.delegate = self;) I get a warning saying "class MYCLASS does not implement the UITextDelegate protocol".  Any ideas what that is?  Thanks again!!!

Comment: btw, any chance you can help with this one, been working on it for days --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338318/uitextview-paging-enabled-text-cut-off  Thanks!

Comment: If MYCLASS is one of your UIViewControllers, then it should look similar to the live I have above, i.e., you need to add <UIScrollViewDelegate> to the end of the line.

Comment: Not sure about that other question myself, sorry. :)

Comment: I got it, instead of adding  <UIScrollViewDelegate>, I added <UITextViewDelegate> and it worked with no warning.  I guess it's because I was using it with UITextView.  THANKS AGAIN FOR YOUR HELP!!!  (and thanks for looking at the other one too, really appreciate it!)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    weak var textView: UITextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.textView.delegate = self
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        ...
    }
}
```

[UITextViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate) inherits [UIScrollViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate)